# Cross domain resize iframe after content change

Tags: javascript, html, perl, iframe

Before I ask, know that I am fairly new to HTML. I have read every topic about cross-domain resizing, but haven't found a suitable answer.

The iframe in question is being dynamically loaded with a Perl script. Within the iframe, there's a form with a button that generates different types of reports that the user might request. Basically, it changes the content of the iframe by reinvoking the script, but doesn't reload the entire page. I am able to resize the iframe on the initial load with

```
onload="parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, target_domain);"
```

in the `body` tag , but not after a new report is generated.

Is there somewhere else that I can put the same `parent.postMessage` call to send the new height to the event listener on the parent page?